# Mongodb collection created through Spring Boot API POST isn't displayed in 'mongosh' shell

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository, mongosh

I've created a Spring Boot REST API to create and store Books. This API has a POST `createBook()` and a GET `getAll()` request. Both requests are working fine, using the method GET http:localhost:8080/books I can see the list of books that I created. The problem is that I needed to execute a query to replace all books with price null to 0, so I was trying to perform that query in 'mongosh'. In the 'mongosh' shell I used the database that I created for this API but there are no collections inside it.

Note: For now I am not using any authentication.

BookService.java:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {

    // Wire the controller to the "BookRepository" for data access
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllBooks() {
        List<Book> books = bookRepository.findAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(books);
    }

    // Other methods bellow...
```

BookRepository.java:

```java
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<Book, String> { }
```

application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/book_app_db
```

POSTMAN request:

```
GET localhost:8080/books
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "id": "65b95dc2ddb7f820a72bff76",
        "title": "title1",
        "author": "author1",
        "isbn": "9765453734",
        "category": null,
        "price": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "65b95e9bddb7f820a72bff77",
        "title": "title2",
        "author": "author2",
        "isbn": "9765355634",
        "category": null,
        "price": null
    },
    {
        "id": "65b95fc2ddb7f820a72bff78",
        "title": "title3",
        "author": "author3",
        "isbn": "97653567834",
        "category": null,
        "price": null
    },
    ...
]
```

mongosh (mongo shell):

```
C:\Users\ASUS>mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 65c3a4aea4c573e16eb447ec
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.1.3
Using MongoDB:          7.0.5
Using Mongosh:          2.1.3

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/


   The server generated these startup warnings when booting
   2024-02-03T16:26:40.694+00:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted


test> show databases
admin           40.00 KiB
book_app_db      8.00 KiB
config         108.00 KiB
local           72.00 KiB
test_database   72.00 KiB
test> use book_app_db
switched to db book_app_db
book_app_db> show collections

book_app_db>
```

I tried to use 'show collections' to see the book collection. I expected to see the collection books containing the same documents returned in the GET request.

I also tried to create a new database from 'mongosh' to verify if I could insert documents manually and if the `find()` was working and it did - I was able to create a table, a collection and documents and then display them using the `find()`.

Comment: Are you sure that the table is `books` instead of `book`? From my experience it defaults to take the name of your Java class. I.e. if I make a `@Document class User { }` my mongo will have a table called `user`, not `users`.

Comment: Jesser, you're right, my @Document class name is indeed Book, which means that the collection name is 'book'. I initially created this 'books' collection manually because I thought that was the correct way to implement MongoDB, but actually, I noticed that it creates the collection automatically when you do the first insertion on the database (POST createBook()). So to verify this I even deleted the 'books' collection and the GET request keeps returning all the books saved in the collection. So at this point, I don't understand why my database collections aren't being displayed in 'mongosh'

Comment: I've found the origin of the problem: I was using a docker container to run the app, so the configurations in compose.yaml were overriding the application.properties. My API data was being sent to the container to a default created database. I opened a shell in my app docker container through Docker Desktop and verified that 'book' collection was there and inside it all the data that my API is fetching.
Thank you for your help and sorry for the confusion, I am still learning how docker works.